# #include <TBPubSubClient.h>

Tags: compiler-errors, arduino, compilation, publish-subscribe, esp32

Even though I've downloaded all the necessary libraries, I'm still getting an error during compilation. The code I'm trying to compile is from the example library of ThingsBoard. What could be the reason? The compilation error is as follows:

"In file included from C:\Users\YAZILIMM\AppData\Local\Temp.arduinoIDE-unsaved2023913-7500-15j0apg.1lt4\0002-arduino_rpc\0002-arduino_rpc.ino:9:
d:\Belgeler\Arduino\libraries\ThingsBoard\src/Arduino_MQTT_Client.h:10:10: fatal error: TBPubSubClient.h: No such file or directory
#include <TBPubSubClient.h>
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.

exit status 1

Compilation error: exit status 1"

I removed and reinstalled the libraries. I checked if my Windows username conforms to English characters. I reinstalled the libraries. I uninstalled and reinstalled the Arduino IDE program.

The libraries being used are as follows:`#include <ThingsBoard.h>`
`#include <Arduino_MQTT_Client.h>`
`#include <WiFiEspClient.h>`
`#include <WiFiEsp.h>`
`#include <SoftwareSerial.h>`

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#define THINGSBOARD_ENABLE_PROGMEM 0
#elif defined(ESP32) || defined(RASPBERRYPI_PICO) || defined(RASPBERRYPI_PICO_W)
#include <WiFi.h>
#endif

#ifndef LED_BUILTIN
#define LED_BUILTIN 99
#endif

#include <Arduino_MQTT_Client.h>
#include <ThingsBoard.h>

constexpr char WIFI_SSID[] = "YOUR_WIFI_SSID";
constexpr char WIFI_PASSWORD[] = "YOUR_WIFI_PASSWORD";

// See https://thingsboard.io/docs/getting-started-guides/helloworld/
// to understand how to obtain an access token
constexpr char TOKEN[] = "YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN";

// Thingsboard we want to establish a connection too
constexpr char THINGSBOARD_SERVER[] = "demo.thingsboard.io";
// MQTT port used to communicate with the server, 1883 is the default unencrypted MQTT port.
constexpr uint16_t THINGSBOARD_PORT = 1883U;

// Maximum size packets will ever be sent or received by the underlying MQTT client,
// if the size is to small messages might not be sent or received messages will be discarded
constexpr uint32_t MAX_MESSAGE_SIZE = 1024U;

// Baud rate for the debugging serial connection.
// If the Serial output is mangled, ensure to change the monitor speed accordingly to this variable
constexpr uint32_t SERIAL_DEBUG_BAUD = 115200U;


// Initialize underlying client, used to establish a connection
WiFiClient wifiClient;
// Initalize the Mqtt client instance
Arduino_MQTT_Client mqttClient(wifiClient);
// Initialize ThingsBoard instance with the maximum needed buffer size
ThingsBoard tb(mqttClient, MAX_MESSAGE_SIZE);

// Attribute names for attribute request and attribute updates functionality

constexpr char BLINKING_INTERVAL_ATTR[] = "blinkingInterval";
constexpr char LED_MODE_ATTR[] = "ledMode";
constexpr char LED_STATE_ATTR[] = "ledState";

// handle led state and mode changes
volatile bool attributesChanged = false;

// LED modes: 0 - continious state, 1 - blinking
volatile int ledMode = 0;

// Current led state
volatile bool ledState = false;

// Settings for interval in blinking mode
constexpr uint16_t BLINKING_INTERVAL_MS_MIN = 10U;
constexpr uint16_t BLINKING_INTERVAL_MS_MAX = 60000U;
volatile uint16_t blinkingInterval = 1000U;

uint32_t previousStateChange;

// For telemetry
constexpr int16_t telemetrySendInterval = 2000U;
uint32_t previousDataSend;

// List of shared attributes for subscribing to their updates
constexpr std::array<const char *, 2U> SHARED_ATTRIBUTES_LIST = {
  LED_STATE_ATTR,
  BLINKING_INTERVAL_ATTR
};

// List of client attributes for requesting them (Using to initialize device states)
constexpr std::array<const char *, 1U> CLIENT_ATTRIBUTES_LIST = {
  LED_MODE_ATTR
};

/// @brief Initalizes WiFi connection,
// will endlessly delay until a connection has been successfully established
void InitWiFi() {
  Serial.println("Connecting to AP ...");
  // Attempting to establish a connection to the given WiFi network
  WiFi.begin(WIFI_SSID, WIFI_PASSWORD);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    // Delay 500ms until a connection has been succesfully established
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println("Connected to AP");
}

/// @brief Reconnects the WiFi uses InitWiFi if the connection has been removed
/// @return Returns true as soon as a connection has been established again
const bool reconnect() {
  // Check to ensure we aren't connected yet
  const wl_status_t status = WiFi.status();
  if (status == WL_CONNECTED) {
    return true;
  }

  // If we aren't establish a new connection to the given WiFi network
  InitWiFi();
  return true;
}


/// @brief Processes function for RPC call "setLedMode"
/// RPC_Data is a JSON variant, that can be queried using operator[]
/// See https://arduinojson.org/v5/api/jsonvariant/subscript/ for more details
/// @param data Data containing the rpc data that was called and its current value
/// @return Response that should be sent to the cloud. Useful for getMethods
RPC_Response processSetLedMode(const RPC_Data &data) {
  Serial.println("Received the set led state RPC method");

  // Process data
  int new_mode = data;

  Serial.print("Mode to change: ");
  Serial.println(new_mode);

  if (new_mode != 0 && new_mode != 1) {
    return RPC_Response("error", "Unknown mode!");
  }

  ledMode = new_mode;

  attributesChanged = true;

  // Returning current mode
  return RPC_Response("newMode", (int)ledMode);
}


// Optional, keep subscribed shared attributes empty instead,
// and the callback will be called for every shared attribute changed on the device,
// instead of only the one that were entered instead
const std::array<RPC_Callback, 1U> callbacks = {
  RPC_Callback{ "setLedMode", processSetLedMode }
};


/// @brief Update callback that will be called as soon as one of the provided shared attributes changes value,
/// if none are provided we subscribe to any shared attribute change instead
/// @param data Data containing the shared attributes that were changed and their current value
void processSharedAttributes(const Shared_Attribute_Data &data) {
  for (auto it = data.begin(); it != data.end(); ++it) {
    if (strcmp(it->key().c_str(), BLINKING_INTERVAL_ATTR) == 0) {
      const uint16_t new_interval = it->value().as<uint16_t>();
      if (new_interval >= BLINKING_INTERVAL_MS_MIN && new_interval <= BLINKING_INTERVAL_MS_MAX) {
        blinkingInterval = new_interval;
        Serial.print("Blinking interval is set to: ");
        Serial.println(new_interval);
      }
    } else if (strcmp(it->key().c_str(), LED_STATE_ATTR) == 0) {
      ledState = it->value().as<bool>();
      if (LED_BUILTIN != 99) {
        digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, ledState);
      }
      Serial.print("LED state is set to: ");
      Serial.println(ledState);
    }
  }
  attributesChanged = true;
}

void processClientAttributes(const Shared_Attribute_Data &data) {
  for (auto it = data.begin(); it != data.end(); ++it) {
    if (strcmp(it->key().c_str(), LED_MODE_ATTR) == 0) {
      const uint16_t new_mode = it->value().as<uint16_t>();
      ledMode = new_mode;
    }
  }
}

const Shared_Attribute_Callback attributes_callback(&processSharedAttributes, SHARED_ATTRIBUTES_LIST.cbegin(), SHARED_ATTRIBUTES_LIST.cend());
const Attribute_Request_Callback attribute_shared_request_callback(&processSharedAttributes, SHARED_ATTRIBUTES_LIST.cbegin(), SHARED_ATTRIBUTES_LIST.cend());
const Attribute_Request_Callback attribute_client_request_callback(&processClientAttributes, CLIENT_ATTRIBUTES_LIST.cbegin(), CLIENT_ATTRIBUTES_LIST.cend());

void setup() {
  // Initalize serial connection for debugging
  Serial.begin(SERIAL_DEBUG_BAUD);
  if (LED_BUILTIN != 99) {
    pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
  }
  delay(1000);
  InitWiFi();
}

void loop() {
  delay(10);

  if (!reconnect()) {
    return;
  }

  if (!tb.connected()) {
    // Connect to the ThingsBoard
    Serial.print("Connecting to: ");
    Serial.print(THINGSBOARD_SERVER);
    Serial.print(" with token ");
    Serial.println(TOKEN);
    if (!tb.connect(THINGSBOARD_SERVER, TOKEN, THINGSBOARD_PORT)) {
      Serial.println("Failed to connect");
      return;
    }
    // Sending a MAC address as an attribute
    tb.sendAttributeData("macAddress", WiFi.macAddress().c_str());

    Serial.println("Subscribing for RPC...");
    // Perform a subscription. All consequent data processing will happen in
    // processSetLedState() and processSetLedMode() functions,
    // as denoted by callbacks array.
    if (!tb.RPC_Subscribe(callbacks.cbegin(), callbacks.cend())) {
      Serial.println("Failed to subscribe for RPC");
      return;
    }

    if (!tb.Shared_Attributes_Subscribe(attributes_callback)) {
      Serial.println("Failed to subscribe for shared attribute updates");
      return;
    }

    Serial.println("Subscribe done");

    // Request current states of shared attributes
    if (!tb.Shared_Attributes_Request(attribute_shared_request_callback)) {
      Serial.println("Failed to request for shared attributes");
      return;
    }

    // Request current states of client attributes
    if (!tb.Client_Attributes_Request(attribute_client_request_callback)) {
      Serial.println("Failed to request for client attributes");
      return;
    }
  }

  if (attributesChanged) {
    attributesChanged = false;
    if (ledMode == 0) {
      previousStateChange = millis();
    }
    tb.sendTelemetryData(LED_MODE_ATTR, ledMode);
    tb.sendTelemetryData(LED_STATE_ATTR, ledState);
    tb.sendAttributeData(LED_MODE_ATTR, ledMode);
    tb.sendAttributeData(LED_STATE_ATTR, ledState);
  }

  if (ledMode == 1 && millis() - previousStateChange > blinkingInterval) {
    previousStateChange = millis();
    ledState = !ledState;
    tb.sendTelemetryData(LED_STATE_ATTR, ledState);
    tb.sendAttributeData(LED_STATE_ATTR, ledState);
    if (LED_BUILTIN == 99) {
      Serial.print("LED state changed to: ");
      Serial.println(ledState);
    } else {
      digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, ledState);
    }
  }

  // Sending telemetry every telemetrySendInterval time
  if (millis() - previousDataSend > telemetrySendInterval) {
    previousDataSend = millis();
    tb.sendTelemetryData("temperature", random(10, 20));
    tb.sendAttributeData("rssi", WiFi.RSSI());
    tb.sendAttributeData("channel", WiFi.channel());
    tb.sendAttributeData("bssid", WiFi.BSSIDstr().c_str());
    tb.sendAttributeData("localIp", WiFi.localIP().toString().c_str());
    tb.sendAttributeData("ssid", WiFi.SSID().c_str());
  }

  tb.loop();
}
```

Comment: Please edit the question to include the code causing the error.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't understand the reason, but after installing the old version of the 'thingsboard.h' library and then updating to the latest version again, the issue was resolved. In the new version, 'TBPubSubClient.h' was not present, whereas it existed in the old version.